# Defining a number as an image

Tags: c++

So I am making a 2d game hardcoded with wxWidgets, and I'd like at the top to say something like #Define 2 hero.png or wall.png or monster.png, etc. So my idea was originally to just swap values in the matrix, and move the png around but how can I define the object so when the program reads my grid, it know what png to use? All help is greatly appreciated.

My Grid is like:

```
{0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,2,1,1,1}
{0,0,0,0,0,1}
{0,0,0,0,0,1}
{0,3,1,1,1,0}
```

Comment: `2` cannot be a preprocessor macro name.  (Thank goodness.)

Answer (score -1):

You can create a dictionary that relates the number to the image name.

You can use the following syntax:

```
std::map<char, const char*> my_map = {
    { '1', 'hero.png' },
    { '2', 'wall.png' },
    { '3', 'monster.png' }
};
```

And you can search by the number inside this map. The docs are:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Comment: Multiple-character `char`s are implementation defined, and won't do anything useful here.  You probably meant `const char*` and `"hero.png"`.

Comment: You are right! Thank you!
My bad copying and pasting.